# Delete-Upsert-Read Access Pattern in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I use Cassandra to store trading information. Based on the queries available, I design my CF as below:

```
CREATE trades (trading_book text,
               trading_date timestamp,
               OTHER TRADING INFO ...,
               PRIMARY KEY (trading_book, trading_date));
```

I want to delete all the data on a given date in the following way:

1. collect all the trading books (which are stored somewhere else);
2. evenly distribute all the trading books in 20 threads;
3. in each thread, loop through the books, and

DELETE FROM trades WHERE trading_book='A_BOOK' AND
                         trading_date='2015-01-01'

There are about 1 million trades and the deletion takes 2 min to complete. Then insert the trading data on 2015-01-01 again (about 1 million trades) immediate after the deletion done.

When the insertion done and I re-read the data, I got the error even with query timeout set to 600 seconds:

```
ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'} info={'received_responses': None, 'required_responses': None, 'consistency': 'Not Set'}
```

It looks like some data inconsistency in the CF now, i.e. the coordinator could identify the partition, but there is no data on the partition?

Is there anything wrong with my access pattern? How to solve this problem?

Any hints will be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating tombstones for every column on that date (by doing the deletes), then writing new records over the top.  So now each read must first read the original column, then the tombstone, then the new record.  If you do a trace you will see that tombstone reads are killing you.  This kind of pattern is problematic with Cassandra, so you should try to find a different (immutable) way to do this.  An alternative could be to simply overwrite the data, in which case there are no tombstones to reconcile.  But you'll still have to deal with two versions.

Comment: Also you should make sure you understand how keys work in Cassandra (i.e. the difference between the partition key and clustering columns). In your case `trading_book` is your partition key while `trading_date` is a clustering column.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Following question: I have tombstones now in the CF, how could I delete the tombstones? Does that mean no matter however I tried, the tombstone marked "rows" could not be retrieved any more? As to the partition key, we have the query pattern "given a book, find all the trades across dates in it", so I think the key setting is fine upto now.

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html) out for more info on tombstones and deletes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to rs_atl's response (which hits the nail on the had with tombstones) here's a bit of info for you to understand / address the problem:

#### What are tombstones anyway?

Because sstables are immutable, rather than deleting records in Cassandra, we insert a new cell that essentially holds a null value. That's a tombstone. Tombstones become available for deletion or garbage collection after gc_grace seconds (configurable by table).

#### Tombstones and repairs:

The reason we wait is to ensure that c* has time to propagate a tombstone to all replicas. If a tombstone does not get replicated to all replicas (in some edge cases with low CL writes and flopping nodes for example) and then gets removed / gc'ed, the original data that was deleted will come back to life. This is why we run repairs at least every GC_Grace, ensuring tombstone consistency and preventing zombie data.

#### How many tombstones am I hitting?

If you turn on tracing in cqlsh `tracing on` or turn on probabilistic tracing in the yaml or via nodetool you'll be able to see how many tombstones you are hitting for a particular request. As this number gets bigger, your read performance will decrease until you see the timeouts you mentioned.

`nodetool cfstats` also gives you more macro details (average tombstones per slice) of how many tombstones are in your table.

the `sstablemetadata` utility shows you the total # of tombstones in a table.

#### What can I do to get rid of tombstones?

1) If you're deleting everything in the table, truncate table is a way of deleting data for free in c* since you can expire entire sstables.

2) Tombstones are removed by compaction. You can more aggressively delete tombstones by decreasing `gc_grace_seconds` and/or increasing the [tombstone ratio](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html) for compaction, but make sure you're running your repairs or you may see zombie data.

Comment: Thank you! The "What can I do to get rid of tombstones?" helps!